# error using for in qt with opencv3

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I get source code example from MitrocontrollersAndMore about licence plate recognition using c++. But I found some errors. For example, I have error in this code:

```
for (auto &vectorOfMatchingChars : vectorOfVectorsOfMatchingCharsInScene) {                     // for each group of matching chars
        PossiblePlate possiblePlate = extractPlate(imgOriginalScene, vectorOfMatchingChars);        // attempt to extract plate

        if (possiblePlate.imgPlate.empty() == false) {                                              // if plate was found
            vectorOfPossiblePlates.push_back(possiblePlate);                                        // add to vector of possible plates
        }
    }
```

The errors are expected initializer before ':' token, expected primary-expression at the end of input, expected ';' at end of input, etc. What must I do to solve these errors?

Comment: You have enabled the standard C++11

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your .pro like this ::

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++14
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
```

focus on c++14. This enables C++14 version.

Since I dont know how you .pro looks like hence I have given an example here.

to enable C++14 you need to add specifically this line::

CONFIG += c++14